# Keeping up with standards, new releases and deprecations

Tags: standards, deprecated

I want to know how programmers keep up with changes in a package or library. I usually go over the release notes. 
How to keep up with the standards and maintain good coding practices?
Thanks

**Edit** 
By "maintaining good coding practices" I mean is how to keep code efficient and optimized based on changes in the standard/release? For e.g: remove deprecated code, use new features.

I am just wondering what is the right way to go about it? If some feature is deprecated from one version to next do people go and change it in their codebase asap?
Thanks Stack Overflow, I learn a lot here :)

Comment: This is an awfully general question.  You seem to be asking how people keep up with changes in packages, libraries, coding practices, and standards.  It would help if you'd narrow it some.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I typically look over release notes.

If you need to track the versions and do a full tracability analysis on them from package to vendor, I would research tracability software.

Spreadsheets don't cut it. :)

Comment: Any open source tracability software suggestions?

Comment: @spyder: Unfortunately - no, I have not worked with or evaluated any open source traceability software.